# axios POST request not triggering response in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

just started working on a MERN project. So I am sending this POST request from client side. Here is the code

```
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const user_info = {
    username:this.state.username,
    password:this.state.password,
  }
 axios.post('http://localhost:5000/weather/usercreated',user_info)
 .then((res)=>{console.log(res.data)}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
}
```

So from what I see from backend, the POST request is working. But the problem with the front end code is, this part:

```
then((res)=>console.log(res.data))
```

the response is not showing in console. 
I need some help.

The following is the code I put in the backend

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/userid');


let user_info = ''
router.post('/usercreated',(req,res)=>{

    const username = req.body.username
    const password = req.body.password

    user_info = new User({
        username,
        password,
    })

    user_info.save().then(()=>res.json('added'))
})

module.exports=router
```

Thanks

Comment: In the backend, are you returning the response, and if yes, how?

Comment: in the backend it is returning response that I defined in the backend.

Comment: Can you show us that code, please?

Comment: and if you use a tool like POSTMAN, there is any return? or in the developer tools of the browser, in the network tab, do you see it?

Comment: yes, hold on let me update it to my question

Comment: i understand what u saying, and yes it is supposed to have a response that can be seen in browse console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215959/discussion-between-learnersamuelx-and-sebastian-cristi-castillo).

Comment: do this `res.send('added')`

Comment: in the backend ?? zb22

Comment: yes, instead of `res.json('added')` use `res.send('added')`

Comment: tried, but no change

Comment: Check for the response on the devtools network pannel, is it pending or finished?

Comment: status 204 and time 3ms

Answer (score 0):

Check that the server is actually returning data. You can console log res and check the object in the console.